# Portable Executable Export File Name field

Tags: portable-executable

One of the field of the IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY structure is 'Name'. According to the COFF spec, this field contains the name of the PE file which exports the symbols. I can programmatically read this field. It does really reference the name of the file which exports the symbols. But, can someone explains the meaning of this field? Why does it actually exist? It looks like it could be used as double-check..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Name` field in `IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY` contains the internal name of the module (i.e. original name that was used while building the module). This is useful in the cases where the actual file itself is renamed. For example, NT kernel that supports PAE is named as `ntkrnlpa.exe`. But, the `Name` field in its `IMAGE_EXPORT_DIRECTORY` struct still contains `ntoskrnl.exe`.

Comment: You can also use Dependency Walker to traverse through PE file structs and tables: http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Having this information field. I don't yet see the real reason for having such a field. Any idea WHY this field exists and where it is used for?